# Checklist for asking questions

Tags: discussion

Before asking a question on cstheory you should ...

Answer (score 4):

Try finding the answer to your question yourself by checking

#### General

1. [Google](http://www.google.com)
2. [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com)
3. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org)

#### Specific

1. [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo)
2. [A compendium of NP optimization problems](http://www.nada.kth.se/%7Eviggo/wwwcompendium/)
3. [Open Problem Garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/)
4. [Information System on Graph Classes and their Inclusions](http://www.graphclasses.org/)

Comment: *Specific </spelling-nazi>